# SQL Server: limit SELECT to only fetch data from last 4 weeks / 1 month

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures

I am using a simple stored procedure to fetch some data from a database which works fine so far.

Can someone here tell me how I have to amend this so that it always goes back 4 weeks resp. 1 month from the current date. 
I would like to use the column "dateEsc" (formatted as datetime) and only want the stored procedure to fetch items with a date stamp there that is max. 4 weeks older than the current date.

**My stored procedure:**

```
**ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CountQueue]
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT      dateEsc,
            url,
            EID
FROM        QueueLog
WHERE       logStatus = 'New'
AND         region = 'US'
AND         (
                flag = 'flag1' 
                OR 
                flag = 'flag2'
            )
ORDER BY    dateEsc desc, EID desc
END**
```

Many thanks for any help with this Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted *exactly* four weeks, you would use:

```
WHERE dateesc >= getdate() - 28
```

If you wanted four weeks, but not worried about the time component:

```
WHERE dateesc >= cast(getdate() - 28 as date)
```

If you wanted *exactly* one month:

```
WHERE dateesc >= dateadd(month, -1, getdate())
```

And if you wanted one month, but not worried about the time component:

```
WHERE dateesc >= cast(dateadd(month, -1, getdate()) as date)
```

You would then add these conditions to your `where` clause.